# error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:

Tags: git-merge, railstutorial.org

Thanks in advance for the help!

I was just finishing up chapter 6 of Rails Tutorial:

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#sec-6_4

I ran:

```
❤ git checkout master
```

Which went fine and then I ran:

```
❤ git merge modeling-users
```

And got the following error:

```
Updating fc9f72a..90d1ba6
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        app/models/user.rb
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

This is my app/models/user.rb file:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  email      :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

And now my Sublime Text 2 user_spec.rb and application_helper_spec.rb files wont save and get the following errors:

> Unable to save ~/code/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/models/user_spec.rb

user_spec.rb:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  email      :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", 
                     password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@bax.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        @user.should be_valid
      end
      end
  end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        @user.should be_valid
      end      
    end
  end

  describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password is not present" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password confirmation is nil" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "with a password that's too short" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
    it { should be_invalid }
  end

  describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by_email(@user.email) }

    describe "with valid password" do
      it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

      it { should_not == user_for_invalid_password }
      specify { user_for_invalid_password.should be_false }
    end
  end
end
```

and my application_helper_spec.rb file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApplicationHelper do

  describe "full_title" do
    it "should include the page title" do
      full_title("foo").should =~ /foo/
    end

    it "should include the base title" do
      full_title("foo").should =~ /^Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App/
    end

    it "should not include a bar for the home page" do
      full_title("").should_not =~ /\|/
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error `The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge` is happening because there is a `app/models/user.rb` file in the folder which is currently not added to any branch.

You can verify this by running the `git status` command; it should show an output similar to the following:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   app/models/user.rb
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

When you run `git merge modeling-users`, it is trying to merge the `modeling-users` branch to `master` branch. The `modeling-users` branch already has a copy of `app/models/user.rb` included in it. The merge command is making it overwrite the untracked version of the file with the one already within the `modeling-users` branch. Hence the error message to warn you about possibly losing something you want to keep.

As the `git status` message indicates, add the file to the master branch by running `git add app/models/user.rb` command.

The `Unable to save ~/code/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/models/user_spec.rb` message seems to be unrelated to this. Not much can be made out of the error message; perhaps there is more info somewhere else.

It might help to close the project and re-open it again. You may also want to try saving the files in a different editor (vim, perhaps?)